# Access data in collections

Tags: java

I'm using a java library https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-java-scraper. 
One of its method is to get a list of data based on the model `Media`

```
Collection<Media> list = tag.getMediaRating().getMedia().getNodes();
System.out.println(list.toArray()[0]);
```

This is part of the output from printing the list

```
Media(height=1350, width=1080)
```

This is the model class `Media`

```
public class Media {
    protected Integer height;
    protected Integer width;
}
```

Is there anyway I am able to access the height and the width value individually? I am actually unsure of the data structure that is presented

Comment: I don't see any getter methods for those attributes, so you'll most likely have to use reflection unless you're willing to fork the repository and edit it.

Comment: The object printed is media object. Try printing list.toArray()[0].height and list.toArray()[0].width

Comment: @PriyaJain The attributes are not `public`.

Comment: The library is using Lombok to generate getters and setters. Try doing `list.toArray()[0].getHeight()`

Comment: Didn't notice that. As suggested you can use getter setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [GitHub](https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-java-scraper) page for the library, they are using [Project Lombok](https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-java-scraper#ide-lombok-plugin) to auto-generate their getters and setters.

```
list.toArray()[0].getHeight();
list.toArray()[0].getWidth();
```

The above lines of code should work and compile, even though the methods are not defined in the source code.

See the main [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) site for more information.